# Сharacter Сontrol script based on specific int variables is not working. How to solve this problem?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my project, I'm trying to use brainwaves to control a character. The BCI device transmits wave data. Below is a script that contains helper methods to work with my BCI values.

```
///<summary>
///
///     Contains helper methods for working with the Neurosky Mindwave values.
///
///</summary>
public static class MindwaveHelper
{

    #region Attributes

        // Constants & Statics
        
        // Maximum "eSense" value (meditaiton or attention)
        public const int SENSE_MAX = 100;

        // Maximum blink strength value
        public const int BLINK_MAX = 200;

        // The maximum value of "poorSignalLevel", meaning that the headset has no signal
        public const int NO_SIGNAL_LEVEL = 200;

    #endregion


    #region Public Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates a ratio of a given sense value (meditation or attention).
        /// </summary>
        public static float GetSenseRatio(int _SenseValue)
        {
            return (_SenseValue / SENSE_MAX);
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates the ratio of the given blink strength value.
        /// </summary>
        public static float GetBlinkRatio(int _BlinkValue)
        {
            return (_BlinkValue / BLINK_MAX);
        }

    #endregion

}
```

I want to apply the received data to the capsule in the unit to make it move at least straight and backward. For this, I want to use the Meditation value and the following logic: If meditation >= 75 -> character moves forward If meditation <= 40 -> character moves reverse.

Here is the script for character control:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float _moveSpeed = 5f; // Speed of the player movement
    [SerializeField]
    private float _gravity = 9.81f; // Gravity to apply to the player
    [Range(0, 75)]
    [SerializeField] private float _Meditation; // The meditation level of the player

    private CharacterController _controller; // Reference to the character controller component

    public enum MindPhase // Enumeration for the different mind phases that can be detected
    {
        None, // No mind phase detected
        Meditation // Meditation phase detected
    }

    void Start()
    {
        _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>(); // Get the character controller component from the player object
    }

    void Update()
    { 
        // Normalize the meditation level to a value between 0 and 1
        _Meditation = Mathf.Clamp01(_Meditation / (float)MindwaveHelper.SENSE_MAX);
        
        // Calculate the movement direction based on the meditation level
        var x = Mathf.Clamp((_Meditation - MindwaveHelper.SENSE_MAX) / 35, 0f, 0f);
        var direction = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(x, 0));
        
        // Apply gravity to the movement direction
        direction.y -= _gravity;
        
        // Move the character in the direction calculated above
        _controller.Move(direction * _moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Below is a screenshot from my project, which shows how all brainwave data is output, in particular attention and meditation data. In this case, the meditation level is 69 and the character must stand still, which happens, however, when the meditation level rises above 75 or drops below 40, the capsule is still not moving.

[image]

How this problem can be solved?

Comment: It looks like your local variable `x` will always be 0 because you are clamping the value between 0 and 0.  `var x = Mathf.Clamp((_Meditation - MindwaveHelper.SENSE_MAX) / 35, 0f, 0f);`  Mathf.Clamp is defined as `Clamp(float value, float min, float max);`

Comment: @hijinxbassist True, but when I change ```float min``` to -1f and ```float max``` to 1f, the capsule starts moving in one direction right after starting the game, even without connecting the BCI

Comment: The equations being used do not look right, and the thresholds defined in your question are not present in the code.  I suggest focusing on your equation(s) and then editing your question based on that.  Capsule not moving is solved with my first comment.  Capsule moving without input is due to the equation used to get the value `x`.  Dividing by 35 is a mystery to me, as is subtracting 100 from a normalized value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the 0-1 value from a range, use `Mathf.InverseLerp` which calculates the value `t` from a range based on a value.  If that value goes beyond the range, you get 0 or 1 (based on which direction the value surpasses the range).

For the inverse lerp to work, you need to supply the min and max values of the range.  You specified the min value in your question as thresholds ( > 75 ) & ( < -40 ).  All that is needed now are the upper values.

The value calculated from lower range will need to be inverted since the low end should be in the range of 0 to -1.  No change is needed for the upper ranges calculated value.

Below is a mock up of how to get the value between -1 to 1.  Example values are used for the upper ends of the 2 ranges.

```
// Input value
//
var rawValue = 80;

// Lower Range
//
var lowerMin = -40;
var lowerMax = -100;

// Upper Range
//
var upperMin = 70;
var upperMax = 100;

// Inverse Lerp for upper & lower ranges (get t from range)
//
var lowerRangeT = Mathf.InverseLerp(lowerMin, lowerMax, rawValue);
var upperRangeT = Mathf.InverseLerp(upperMin, upperMax, rawValue);

// Calculate move value
//
var moveValueNormalized = upperRangeT - lowerRangeT;


Debug.Log($"Lower:InverseLerp({lowerMin}, {lowerMax}, {rawValue}) = {lowerRangeT}");
Debug.Log($"Upper:InverseLerp({upperMin}, {upperMax}, {rawValue}) = {upperRangeT}");

Debug.Log($"Move: {moveValueNormalized}");
```

Then use the calculated value `moveValueNormalized` in your final movement equation.